# copy 1d element 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, memcpy

I have a 2d array and need to copy one 1d element into a single array.
I tried to duplicate my issue in below example. But below example doesn't even compile, `gcc` complains

> subscripted value is neither array nor pointer`

at line `TwoDArray[9][99] = 99;`, why is that? I don't quite understand, any help would be appreciated!

```
int main(void)
{
  int i = 0;
  int* TwoDArray;
  int DestArr[100] = {0};

  TwoDArray = calloc(10,sizeof(int*));
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    TwoDArray[i] = calloc(100,sizeof(int));

  TwoDArray[9][99] = 99;

  memcpy(DestArr, &TwoDArray[9],sizeof(int)*100);
  printf("DestArr[99] %d\n",DestArr[99]);


return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT1:**

I mistakenly didn't declare `int** TwoDArray` as pointer to pointer - after changing this, it now compiles flawlessly but the value in my result is `0` and I'd expect it to be `99` - why is this?

Comment: int* is not a two dimensional array or pointer.

Comment: Hoops, mistake in my question... let mer edit, sorry!

Comment: change to `int** TwoDArray;`... `memcpy(DestArr, TwoDArray[9],sizeof(int)*100);`

Comment: I'd change `int* TwoDArray;` to `int** TwoDArray;`. Don't think it's required but maybe `TwoDArray[i] = calloc(100,sizeof(int));` to `TwoDArray[i] = (int*)calloc(100,sizeof(int));`

Comment: Change `&TwoDArray[9]` in memcpy to just `TwoDArray[9]`

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `TwoDArray` is a pointer, pointer to an `int`.

So, the memory allocation should look like

```
 TwoDArray = calloc(10,sizeof(*TwoDArray));  //i.e., sizeof(int)
```

instead of

```
TwoDArray = calloc(10,sizeof(int*));
```

and `TwoDArray[i]` being of type `int`, does not need any `malloc`-ation, whatsoever.

So, you can use `TwoDArray[i]`, provided `i` is within bounds.

`TwoDArray[9][99]` is invalid, as `TwoDArray[9]` is not a pointer, anyway.

Related, to use the array subscript operator,

> `postfix-expression [ expression ]`
>
> One of the expressions shall have type ‘‘pointer to complete object type’’, the other
>   expression shall have integer type, and the result has type ‘‘type’’.

In case of `TwoDArray[9][99]`, `TwoDArray[9]` is certainly not a pointer to complete object type.

---

Edit:

In case you use

```
 int** TwoDArray;
```

and

```
 TwoDArray[i] = calloc(100,sizeof(int));
```

then, you need to change

```
memcpy(DestArr, &TwoDArray[9],sizeof(int)*100);
```

to

```
memcpy(DestArr, TwoDArray[9],sizeof(int)*100);
              ^^
```

as `TwoDArray[9]` *itself* is now the pointer you're interested in, not the *address of the pointer*.

Comment: You can cheat and treat it as pointer `(int*)(TwoDArray[9])[99]`. Not recommended

Comment: Actually, just for the sake of argument, I'd say `TwoDArray[9]` is a pointer that is incorrectly interpreted as a generic number.